# Call org-mode code block by name?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

*Is there a keybinding (or way to define one) to call a source block by its name in the current org-mode buffer?*

Currently, I move mouse pointer inside the code block and then press `C-c C-c`. But this jumping
is becoming distracting as the document gets larger and larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write a function that calls `org-sbe` with the source block name and its arguments and bind it to your favorite key:

```
#+name: call-me
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x="foo"
(message x)
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun call-sb ()
     (interactive)
     (org-sbe call-me (x $"bar")))

  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'call-sb)

#+end_src
```

Here `C-c z` is bound to the command `call-sb` which executess the source block `call-me` with argument `x` bound to the value `"bar"` as a string (without the `$` sign, it is interpreted as a reference to the name `bar` in the Org mode buffer). `org-sbe` is a macro, so its arguments are passed to it unevaluated (in contrast to a function) and it can play games with them (like the `$` interpretation).

See the doc string for `org-sbe`:

```
(org-sbe SOURCE-BLOCK &rest VARIABLES)

Return the results of calling SOURCE-BLOCK with VARIABLES.

Each element of VARIABLES should be a list of two elements: the
first element is the name of the variable and second element is a
string of its value.

So this ‘org-sbe’ construct

 (org-sbe "source-block" (n $2) (m 3))

is the equivalent of the following source code block:

 #+begin_src emacs-lisp :var results=source-block(n=val_at_col_2, m=3) :results silent
 results
 #+end_src

NOTE: The quotation marks around the function name,
’source-block’, are optional.

NOTE: By default, string variable names are interpreted as
references to source-code blocks, to force interpretation of a
cell’s value as a string, prefix the identifier a "$" (e.g.,
"$$2" instead of "$2" or "$@2$2" instead of "@2$2").

NOTE: It is also possible to pass header arguments to the code
block.  In this case a table cell should hold the string value of
the header argument which can then be passed before all variables
as shown in the example below.

| 1 | 2 | :file nothing.png | nothing.png |
#+TBLFM: @1$4='(org-sbe test-sbe $3 (x $1) (y $2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you need new key-bindings? Did you know that you can call code blocks from other code blocks? See https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html

You can bind code block by name in the header (e.g. `:var x=random`) to a variable, and call it by using the variable within the block.

Also, especially if this is for debugging purposes, you can get rid of scrolling by adding `#+CALL:` lines before the block you are working with.

Using your example, place line `#+CALL: call-me()` somewhere in the same document and execute it with C-c C-c. To pass an argument, try `#+CALL: call-me(x="bar")`.

Comment: Could you explain with an example how `#+CALL` works? I tried reading the documentation and found it hard to figure out.

Comment: The idea is that instead of moving somewhere else in the document to execute the code block, you have a call-line somewhere closer to where you work. Using your example, place line `#+CALL: call-me()` somewhere and execute it with `C-c C-c`. To pass an argument, try `#+CALL: call-me(x="bar")`.

Comment: Added the example code paragraph to the answer itself which is the correct place for it.